# Is it normal to attach a catalytic converter with U-bolts?

Tags: exhaust, catalytic-converter

I need to replace my catalytic converter. The current one is held in place by U-bolts. Two U-bolts between the cat and the manifold exhaust pipe (looks like a patch). One holding the exhaust pipe to the exhaust manifold pipe and one U-bolt holding the other end to the muffler.

This doesn't strike me as the best way to put them together. I thought maybe they should be welded together or something so that there's no leaking.

Is it normal to attach a catalytic converter using u-bolts? Or when i replace it should I have it welded?

Comment: To answer your questions directly: No and Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it normal to attach a catalytic converter using u-bolts? Or when i replace it should I have it welded?

It is not normal to utilize u-bolts (muffler clamps) on catalytic converters. They are most often welded in place.